# What does it mean that shift operators “drop any bits beyond the 5th”?

Tags: javascript, bit-shift

From the book “JavaScript: The Definitive Guide”:

> The bitwise operators expect integer operands and behave as if those values were represented as 32-bit integers rather than 64-bit floating-point values.
> These operators convert their operands to numbers, if necessary, and then coerce the numeric values to 32-bit integers by dropping any fractional part and any bits beyond the 32nd.
> The shift operators require a right-side operand between 0 and 31.
> After converting this operand to an unsigned 32-bit integer, they drop any bits beyond the 5th, which yields a number in the appropriate range.
> Surprisingly, NaN, Infinity, and -Infinity all convert to 0 when used as operands of these bitwise operators.

I can’t understand the sentence *“After converting this operand to an unsigned 32-bit integer, they drop any bits beyond the 5th, which yields a number in the appropriate range.”*.

Does the fifth number have any meaning? I’m seeking for proper examples.

Comment: It's not the fifth *number*, it's the fifth *bit* in binary. Any number that is larger that that will get forcefully truncated. Try `((2 ** 31) - 1) | 0` and `(2 ** 31) | 0`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I understand it right nowヾ(ﾟ∀ﾟゞ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The shift operators require a right-side operand between 0 and 31.

Meaning the right-side operand will be between 0b00000 and 0b11111 in binary form, so 5 bits.